# Linq-to-Twitter always error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, unauthorized, linq-to-twitter

I am using LinqToTwitter in my C# desktop application. Trying to send tweets and tweets with image to Twitter using OAuth credentials. Initially I am using these required attributes of my own Twitter application:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentials
    {
        ConsumerKey = "key",
        ConsumerSecret = "secret",
        TwitterAccessToken = "token",
        TwitterAccessTokenSecret = "tokensecret"
    }
};

var context = new TwitterContext(auth);
context.UpdateStatus("Hello World");
```

NOTE: I have double checked that I am using correct values for above keys and tokens, but its always erroring 401 Unauthorized.

NOTE: Also I have checked this link for any mistake: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation

Any help to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine.

The FAQ, which you reference, is the best resource right now.

What type of application are you building, e.g. ASP.NET, Windows Phone, etc.?

You might also try downloading the source code and checking to see if the LinqToTwitterDemos project will work for you.

Comment: I regenerated the Tocken + Token Secret pair at Twitter APP console and it WORKED! The old token and secret was expired. Don't know really what it its lifetime but that worked for me.

Comment: For someone else having similar issue: Please make sure that your account has approved the twitter app through OAuth authentication process.

Comment: Thanks @theGeekster, I added the potential expired token scenario to the FAQ.